# How to register a Custom JavaScriptSerializer in MVC Asp.Net

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a custom object which has a array of an abstract class type.

So as to deserialize it I made a custom JavaScriptSerializer which changes the Json string to a particular type of the abstract class.

Now when I register JavaScriptSerializer I am getting an error "Cannot deserialize object graph into type of ".

The structure of my class is something like

```
class main {
  public int FirstProp {get;set;}
  public List<abstractClass> items {get;set;}
}

class abstractClass 
{
  public int FirstProp {get;set;}
}

class DerviedFirst : abstractClass 
{
  public int CustomProp {get;set;}
}

class DerviedSecond : abstractClass 
{
  public int INeedTHis {get;set;}
}
```

How should I try to achieve this ? i.e. I want to cast the List into individual Class Object types